# Doesnt display the right count in dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the input table

[image: Input]

I cannot get the right count of the sku. I need to achieve this by this dynamic sql. It gives result like below:
[image: Present Result]

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT DISTINCT
        a.'+@primary_column+' AS [No. of distinct'' '+@primary_column+']
        ,sum(case when '+@secondary_column+' is null or '+@secondary_column+' = ''''  then 0 else 1 end) AS ''Total_Count''
        ,STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '',     ['' +'+@secondary_column+'+'']''
                   FROM ['+@TableName+'] b 
                   WHERE b.'+@primary_column+' = a.'+@primary_column+' 
                  FOR XML PATH('''')),1, 1, '''') AS '+@secondary_column+'

        FROM ['+@TableName+'] a
        GROUP BY '+@primary_column+'';

        PRINT(@SQL) 
        EXEC(@SQL)
```

This is the expected output

[image: expected output]

Comment: Why combine SELECT DISTINCT with GROUP BY?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is totally unclear. Please read FAQ, How to Ask and help center as a start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
,sum(case when '+@secondary_column+' is null or '+@secondary_column+' = ''''  then 0 else 1 end) AS ''Total_Count''
```

On this:

```
,COUNT(DISTINCT NULLIF('+@secondary_column+'','''')) ''Total_Count''
```

Full query:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max),
        @secondary_column nvarchar(max) = 'Parent_sku',
        @primary_column nvarchar(max) = 'category',
        @TableName nvarchar(max) = 'SomeTable'


SELECT @sql = '
SELECT  ' + @primary_column + ' AS [No. of distinct'' ' + @primary_column+ '],
        COUNT(DISTINCT ' + @secondary_column + ','''')) Total_count,
        STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '','' + QUOTENAME(ISNULL(' + @secondary_column + ','''')) 
                FROM ' + @TableName + ' s 
                WHERE s.' + @primary_column+ ' = a.' + @primary_column+ ' 
                FOR XML PATH('''')),1,1,'''') as ' + @secondary_column + '
FROM ' + @TableName + ' a
GROUP BY ' + @primary_column 

PRINT @sql

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Output:

```
No. of distinct' category   Total_count Parent_sku
                            1           [TB004]
Kids                        1           [TB003]
Men                         1           [TB001]
Women                       1           [TB002]
```

**EDIT**

F.e. I got this as input:

```
('TB001L', 'TB001', 20, 'AQW2342S', 'Men'),
('TB001S', 'TB001', 21, 'GQW2342S', 'Men'),
('TB002M', 'TB002', 22, 'ZQW2342S', 'Women'),
('TB002S', 'TB002', 23, 'BQW2342S', 'Women'),
('TB003M', 'TB003', 20, 'KQW2342S', 'Kids'),
('TB003S', 'TB003', 23, 'RQW2342S', 'Kids'),
('TB005S', NULL, 22, 'RQW2342S', ''),
('TB005XL', NULL, 23, 'JQW2342S', '')
```

2 last rows is with `NULL` in `@secondary_column`. Output will be:

```
No. of distinct' category   Total_count Parent_sku
                            0           []
Kids                        1           [TB003]
Men                         1           [TB001]
Women                       1           [TB002]
```

Comment: THANKS it works but  i need to integrate this code  at COUNT() for secondary column                                                                                   case when '+@secondary_column+' is null or '+@secondary_column+' = ''''  then 0 else 1 end

Comment: how to do it @gofr1

Comment: For what purpose? `COUNT (DISTINCT` will count exactly what you need. See the edit to my answer. I add `NULLIF` to handle empty values `''` in `@secondary_column`

Comment: this is the problem... https://s32.postimg.org/ongo4w039/hhh.jpg there is no child sku but the count is 1 so i need case when '+@secondary_column+' is null or '+@secondary_column+' = '''' then 0 else 1 end .... how to integrate it ?

Comment: I already add this to my answer. Please, check it. `NULLIF` will handle empty values

Comment: When you use sum, it will no mater of duplicates 1+1 even with same values in that column and you need to count different values in that column. That is why you need to count distinct values and handle `NULLs` and empty values the same way.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH @gofr1